# How to fix a Visual Studio template which tries to include files that the preprocessor can't find?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I don't know the hidden things Visual does for us bellow the hood. I have a *seemingly* broken template, and I don't know how to fix it (or if I'm expected to configure this part myself).

I have downloaded an OpenGL project template for C++. This is the code it generates (the two commented include directives fail, and therefore none of the functions the code calls are found):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL\glew.h>//this one fails
#include <GL\freeglut.h>//this one also fails

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("My Window");
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit()) {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void init(void)
{

}

void display(void)
{

}
```

I believe the problem is that the template doesn't add the folder of those two headers to the list of places where the preprocessor should look for files during an include directive. I don't know where those folders are either... How can I fix the template itself in a manner that those two includes point to the correct folders?

Comment: You must use either forward slashes (`/`) or doubled backslashes (`\\\`).

Comment: @aschepler I'm pretty sure it's not the case with Visual C++, though. E.g. in Visual Studio, its autocomplete completes it with ``\``. I definitely prefer the `/` though.

Answer (score 1):

Download the sources for OpenGL and create a path variable that points to the folder GL so that visual studio can check there for the headers. Or add alternate locations to find source files in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a way add something to the project template so it will automatically download missing source files?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot.

Comment: C++ is not like .NET languages like C#. There's no 'global assembly cache' that can be searched for references. That said, you can use something like [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) package manager to more easily integrate libraries into your projects. For example, you could try adding the [glew](https://www.nuget.org/packages/glew.v140/) package and/or [freeglut](https://www.nuget.org/packages/freeglut/) since you are referencing those.